# If lim $s_n = + \infty$ and inf$\{t_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} > - \infty$, then lim $(s_n + t_n) = + \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's the question: If lim $s_n = + \infty$ and inf$\{t_n | n \in \mathbb{N}\} > - \infty$, then prove that lim $(s_n + t_n) = + \infty$

Here's my proof. Can someone please verify it or offer suggestions for improvement?

Let $m = $ inf$\{t_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Since lim $s_n = \infty$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n > N$, $s_n > M + m$.

This implies that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $s_n - t_n > s_n - m > M$.

That is, $\forall n > N, s_n - t_n < M$

Hence, lim $s_n - t_n = \infty$

Comment: by definition $t_n \geq m$, this does not imply that $-t_n > -m$ which you have claimed in the third line of your proof.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at $s_n+t_n$, right? Not $s_n-t_n$ as you seem to have.

As you started, let $m:= \inf\{t_n\} > -\infty$. Then, for any $M > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
s_n > M - m\quad\forall n\geq N
$$
Hence,
$$
s_n+t_n > M-m + m = M \quad\forall n\geq N
$$
Hence, $\lim (s_n+t_n) = +\infty$